# json array mapping issues with boost json parser

Tags: c++, json, c++11, boost

I am parsing below sample file in below code snippet.

```
{
    "requestType": "INVOCATION",
    "hostName": "localhost",
    "serviceName": "bucky",
    "serviceType": "DISCRETE",
    "serviceParameters": "sampleData",
    "servicesList": [{
        "serviceName": "ABC",
        "serviceParameters": {
            "para1": "value1",
            "para2": "value2",
            "para3": "value3"
        }
    },
    {
        "serviceName": "CBA",
        "serviceParameters": {
            "para1": "value90",
            "para2": "value",
            "para3": "value"
        }
    }],
    "dataTransferMode": null
}
```

### code snippet:

```
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/json_parser.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <sstream>
using boost::property_tree::ptree;
using namespace std;

void print(boost::property_tree::ptree const &pt, vector<string> &service_list, map<string, string> &service_param) {
    using boost::property_tree::ptree;
    ptree::const_iterator end = pt.end();
    string value;
    for (ptree::const_iterator it = pt.begin(); it != end; ++it) {
        // cout<<it->first<<":"<<it->second.get_value<std::string>()<<endl;

        if (it->first == "serviceName") {
            value = it->second.get_value<std::string>();
            service_list.push_back(it->second.get_value<std::string>());
        }

        if (it->first == "para1") {

            service_param[it->first] = it->second.get_value<std::string>();
        }

        if (it->first == "para2") {
            service_param[it->first] = it->second.get_value<std::string>();
        }

        if (it->first == "para3") {
            service_param[it->first] = it->second.get_value<std::string>();
        }

        print(it->second, service_list, service_param);
    }
}

int main() {

    vector<string> service_list;
    map<string, string> service_param_rgbd;
    map<string, map<string, string> > map_name;
    std::ifstream file("sample");
    std::stringstream ss;

    if (file) {
        ss << file.rdbuf();
        cout << "done";
        file.close();
    }

    boost::property_tree::ptree pt;
    boost::property_tree::read_json(ss, pt);

    try {
        BOOST_FOREACH (boost::property_tree::ptree::value_type &v, pt.get_child("servicesList")) {
            assert(v.first.empty()); // array elements have no names
            print(v.second, service_list, service_param_rgbd);
        }

        for (auto itr : service_list) {

            cout << itr << endl;
        }

        for (auto itr : service_param_rgbd) {
            if (find(service_list.begin(), service_list.end(), "ABC") != service_list.end()) {
                map_name["ABC"][itr.first] = itr.second;
            }
        }

        for (auto &i : map_name) {

            for (auto &j : i.second) {
                cout << j.first << ":" << j.second << endl;
            }
        }

        return EXIT_SUCCESS;

    }

    catch (std::exception const &e) {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
    return EXIT_FAILURE
}
```

In above code i need to populate vector and map in order to have mapping between service name and service parameter and for the same map > map_name needs to be created.

so in current scenario inside loop itself i want to create the nested map so that i will have mapping of service name and corresponding parameters . 
As per below code snippet here in outer loop  i->first will iterate the service name and inner loop will provide me  corresponding parameters (para1=>value1,para2=>value2) . This way both service name and corresponding parameters can be tied in one map.

```
for (auto &i : map_name) {
    for (auto &j : i.second) {
        cout << j.first << ":" << j.second << endl;
    }
}
```

Can anybody let me know the efficient approach for the same  as in this approach :

- (a) Separate nested map needs to be created for each of the services.
- (b) same param name for both services name will not work and different-2 services with same param name can't be differentiated.

Comment: -1 for the misindented mess you call code, messed up markup and obvious lack of proofreading. I'm sorry, but after 3+ years and 28 posts on SO, you ought to know better. Please, fix it up.

Comment: Thank you @sehe, you seem to have a godly patience :)

Comment: sorry  @sehe  for that . i was not aware it will be in that shape as suddenly i got trouble in internet connection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The real issue is lack of abstraction.

Simply read into a real data structure:

```
struct service {
    std::string name;

    struct parameters_t {
        std::string para1, para2, para3;
    } parameters;
};
```

That could be as simple as

```
for (auto& v : pt.get_child("servicesList"))
{
    auto& node = v.second;
    service svc;
    svc.name = node.get("serviceName", "");
    svc.parameters.para1 = node.get("serviceParameters.para1", "");
    svc.parameters.para2 = node.get("serviceParameters.para2", "");
    svc.parameters.para3 = node.get("serviceParameters.para3", "");

    if (!services.insert(svc).second)
        std::cout << "skipped duplicate service\n";
}
```

I prefer to make use of Boost `multi_index_container` so I can add multiple indexes if required, but for now just the index by name is required:

```
using Table = bmi::multi_index_container<
    service,
    bmi::indexed_by<
        bmi::ordered_unique<bmi::tag<struct by_name>,
            bmi::member<service, std::string, &service::name>
        >
    >
>;
```

Add a debug printer for `service` objects:

```
static inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, service const& s) {
    return os << "'" << s.name << "' params { "
        << "'" << s.parameters.para1 << "' "
        << "'" << s.parameters.para2 << "' "
        << "'" << s.parameters.para3 << "' }";
}
```

And here's the complete test program, simplified:

```
int main() {
    Table services = read_json("input.txt");

    for (auto& itr : services) {
        std::cout << itr.name << "\n";
    }

    auto it = services.find("ABC");
    assert(it != services.end());
    auto const& abc = *it;

    std::cout << abc << "\n";
}
```

### FULL DEMO

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a484d14b7362eb05)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/property_tree/json_parser.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
using boost::property_tree::ptree;

struct service {
    std::string name;

    struct parameters_t {
        std::string para1, para2, para3;
    } parameters;
};

#include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/ordered_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/member.hpp>

namespace bmi = boost::multi_index;

using Table = bmi::multi_index_container<
    service,
    bmi::indexed_by<
        bmi::ordered_unique<bmi::tag<struct by_name>,
            bmi::member<service, std::string, &service::name>
        >
    >
>;

#include <iostream>

Table read_json(std::string const& fname) {
    Table services;
    boost::property_tree::ptree pt;
    std::ifstream file(fname);
    boost::property_tree::read_json(file, pt);

    for (auto& v : pt.get_child("servicesList"))
    {
        auto& node = v.second;
        service svc;
        svc.name = node.get("serviceName", "");
        svc.parameters.para1 = node.get("serviceParameters.para1", "");
        svc.parameters.para2 = node.get("serviceParameters.para2", "");
        svc.parameters.para3 = node.get("serviceParameters.para3", "");

        if (!services.insert(svc).second)
            std::cout << "skipped duplicate service\n";
    }

    return services;
}

static inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, service const& s) {
    return os << "'" << s.name << "' params { "
        << "'" << s.parameters.para1 << "' "
        << "'" << s.parameters.para2 << "' "
        << "'" << s.parameters.para3 << "' }";
}

int main() {
    Table services = read_json("input.txt");

    for (auto& itr : services) {
        std::cout << itr.name << "\n";
    }

    auto it = services.find("ABC");
    assert(it != services.end());
    auto const& abc = *it;

    std::cout << abc << "\n";
}
```

Prints

```
ABC
CBA
'ABC' params { 'value1' 'value2' 'value3' }
```

Comment: Thanks @sehe for your input and workable solution. I believe we can't have only one structure as diff-2 services will have different and common parameter  with different count as well. I am not sure in this case how the multi index container  will work and i need to generate diff-2 structure based on the name of service as each service will have diff-2 structure. How to modify Table read_json() function in this circumstance i am totally clueless. I need to implement so many for loop for  each service and same can't be achieved through one function and one for loop.

Comment: What is "diff-2"

Comment: Regardless, the key is ALWAYS proper abstraction and data structures. You can apply this approach to any problem, no matter how much more subtle. Post examples and your attempt, and I'll help you get there. Your task as a programmer is to make (and keep) the problem tractible, so you can reason about your program.

Comment: Going the other way is not for humans, it's what compilers and processors are for. They don't care about high level meaning. They only care for efficient execution and calculation.

Comment: I mean to say one service can have 5 parameter and other can have 7 parameter . para1,para2, para3 ....para n  etc. Here para1 value might be same for other services or different  i.e. one service will have {para1,para2,para3} and other service will have para3,para4, para5 and other service can have para11,para12,para13,para3 parameters. so all those parameters can't be placed altogether in one structure. I will have near about  more than  distinct 100 parameters for  diff_2 (different- different) services and those altogether can't be kept in one loop .

Comment: "different-different" doesn't actually explain anything for the - assumed - mental shorthand/stenographic notation "diff_2". I asked for an example. Maybe you can show a JSON that is realistic, preferrably not detached from meaning (hopefully in real life your parameters have useful names and semantics, instead of para11, para78...). I could come up with a design. Right now you're only saying "it can't be XXX for this obfuscated reason diff-2". Tell us what you want/need instead. Not what makes the problem too hard to explain. If you can't explain it, you can't program it.

Comment: Here's a ~3 line edit that give you the `std::map<>` parameters back, if you insist http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/172ec87213bc84f5 (I don't think you should do this, unless you don't actually need to know the parameters at all).

Comment: below is the updated version where you can see the actual json parameter and they way i am parsing to populate the service parameter by clubbing all the parameters of both services in one structure .http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d76f71d3cc7bd3ca.

Comment: Thank you very much for sharing this . Now i no need to include all the service related parameters in structure.

Comment: @sehe : i believe we needn't hardcode  the parameter name as well .

Comment: Anyway same is getting inserted in map and there is no parameter mapping as well in structure. So ideally below code should  have been  be modified .  for (auto name : {"para1", "para2", "para3" })    in  line no. 41 for below link .  coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/172ec87213bc84f5

Comment: That code is exactly the same. You still don't say what your requirements are. I trust you can [write a loop](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/37391bdf047eebb8) yourself (you're using C++ and boost, after all).